# How can I increase the size of the notification bar?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, nexus-5, accessibility

My mom recently got a nexus 5, and she really likes it, but she has moderately bad vision and so she can't see the icons in the notification bar (so she doesn't know when she gets a notification). Can I increase the size of these icons?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but have you tried LCD Density for Root. Requires root access though.